# Printing from an HP Desktjet 1000 Laser printer from a notebook running lubuntu 12.04 x86

Tags: printing

I just connected an HP Deskjet 1000 series to a 148b HP notebook. The notebook reads the printer as (HP Deskjet 1000 j110). After the driver installed and the printer made available under "printing" app," a print test.

Right-clicked the printer icon and selected properties. Under the "settings" tab, I selected "print test page". The "printer state" notification box displayed, "processing-sending data to printer. Then it changes to, "idle-sending data to printer". Which at this point nothing happens. I did this multiple times. Also, re-installed the printer driver. Still the same issue.

I tried the same printer on my desktop running ubuntu 12.04 with unity. The printer works fine.

Is there a reason why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, although mine was an HP Deskjet 1300, and was able to solve it after installing the HP CUPS packages found in **Synaptic**, and the **hplip package**.

Afterwards I opened "printing", just as you did, but instead of going to properties of the identified printer, I decided to add another one. This time I chose "USB" as the root for the printer, and then, after the system searched for the drivers, I selected the box for "Duplexer Installed".

I changed the name of the printer by adding a letter "a", so I did not get confused in between the printers installed, and it worked just fine.

I am not a pro, I just messed around a bit and I am not sure if the packages I downloaded had anything to do, however, I had not seen the "Duplexer Installed" box before.

Finally, I just removed the previous installed printer.

Good luck!